# Wide rows vs Collections in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql, cql3, nosql

I am trying to model many-to-many relationships in Cassandra something like Item-User relationship. User can like many items and item can be bought by many users. Let us also assume that the order in which the "like" event occurs is not a concern and that the most used query is simply returning the "likes" based on item as well as the user.

There are a couple of posts dicussing data modeling
http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/

An alternative would be to store a collection of ItemID in the User table to denote the items liked by that user and do something similar in the Items table in CQL3.

Questions

1. Are there any hits in performance using the collection? I think they translate to composite columns? So the read pattern, caching and other factors should be similar?
2. Are collections less performant for write heavy applications? Is updating the collection frequently less performant?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of advantages of using wide rows over collections that I can think of:

1. The number of elements allowed in a collection is 65535 (an unsigned short).  If it's possible to have more than that many records in your collection, using wide rows is probably better as that limitation is much higher (2 billion cells (rows * columns) per partition).
2. When reading a collection column, the entire collection is read every time.  Compare this to wide row where you can limit the number of rows being read in your query, or limit the criteria of your query based on clustering key (i.e. date > 2015-07-01).

For your particular use case I think modeling an 'items_by_user' table would be more ideal than a `list<item>` column on a 'users' table.

Comment: dont you think if i create `items_by_user` table, then at the time of reading i will have to make a separate SELECT query for reading data ?

Comment: It is not unusual to have to do that.  You just need to think of storing your data in the context of your queries.   If everyone time you are querying for items you need the full user data too, you could store user data in static columns (name, address, etc.) that way they are shared between all items shared by a user.  If you already have the user data from a previous query or you don't need it at all, you wouldn't need that data in items_by_user.

Comment: So is cassandra fit for inserting data into multiple table and also doing multiple SELECT on different table e.g. `Select id FROM table1` and then `SELECT col FROM table2 where rowId = <id from first table>`

Comment: Sure that can work, and if it's a common enough pattern you could pursue putting the data all in one table if it makes sense to do it.

Comment: Your question is slightly off topic, if you need more information, please create a new question and I can provide more info.

Comment: In practical application you can't put all data in one table and surely your data will be distributed in multiple table. e.g Let say you want show a topic so for that to get topic details you will query TOPIC table, to see how many follower you will query FOLLOWER table, to get comments you will query COMMENTS table. so in my opinion i will have to query 3 separate SELECT to show a single tipic. Am I going correct ?

Comment: Hey just as you said that you provide more info so i asked a question pls have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729024/am-i-using-cassandra-efficiently