# Am I using cassandra efficiently?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I have these table

```
CREATE TABLE user_info (
    userId uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    userName varchar,
    fullName varchar,
    sex varchar,
    bizzCateg varchar,
    userType varchar,
    about text,
    joined bigint,
    contact text,
    job set<text>,
    blocked boolean,
    emails set<text>,
    websites set<text>,
    professionTag set<text>,
    location frozen<location>
);

create table publishMsg
(
    rowKey uuid,
    msgId timeuuid,
    postedById uuid,
    title text,
    time bigint,
    details text,
    tags set<text>,
    location frozen<location>,
    blocked boolean,
    anonymous boolean,
    hasPhotos boolean,
    esIndx boolean, 
    PRIMARY KEY(rowKey, msgId)      
) with clustering order by (msgId desc);

create table publishMsg_by_user
(
    rowKey uuid,
    msgId timeuuid,
    title text,
    time bigint,
    details text,
    tags set<text>,
    location frozen<location>,
    blocked boolean,
    anonymous boolean,
    hasPhotos boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY(rowKey, msgId)      
) with clustering order by (msgId desc);

CREATE TABLE followers
(
    rowKey UUID,
    followedBy uuid,
    time bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY(rowKey, orderKey)
);
```

1. I doing 3 INSERT statement in BATCH to put data in `publishMsg` `publishMsg_by_user` `followers` table.
2. To show a single message I have to query three SELECT query on different table:

`publishMsg` - to get a publish message details where `rowkey` & `msgId` given.

`userInfo` - to get `fullName` based on `postedById`

`followers` - to know whether a `postedById` is following a given topic or not

Is this a fit way of using cassandra ? will that be efficient because the given scanerio data can't fit in single table.

Comment: What does 'rowKey' in followers entail?  Is it followers of a particular message, or follower of a particular user?

Comment: Ah, it must be of a user.  When you say 'To show a single message', why do you need to know the followers of a user?

Comment: In `followers` `rowKey` is some topic that is followed by user whose id is `followedBy`. So from this table i want to know if given user is following a given topic or not

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to ask this in an answer but I don't have the rep to comment.

Ignoring the tables for now, what information does your application need to ask for? Ideally in Cassandra, you will only have to execute one query on one table to get the data you need to return to the client. You shouldn't need to have to execute 3 queries to get what you want.

Also, your followers table appears to be missing the orderkey field.

Comment: One info that i need is `show a publish message and whether i am following that message or not` so how will you move ahead?